# Membership sign ups

Tags: drupal, civimember, addresses, postcode

I'd like to vary membership fields for members from different locations, can anyone help?

Essentially I'd like to vary the fields that members are required to fill in when they sign up from a different country. This is specifically with regard to addresses as UK postal addresses have postcodes whereas other countries like Bahrain do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Drupal then you can use [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) + [Webform Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) modules to hide show certain fields.

Else you can add JS to CiviCRM Membership form through extension to hide/show postal code based on country selected.

REF: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/standards/javascript/